# How to set up new AnchorProvider without an AnchorWallet?

Tags: anchor

Is there a simple way to set up a new `AnchorProvider` to create a new `Program` without a connected wallet? Below is a workaround by creating a placeholder wallet, is there a better way?

```
// Create a mock wallet as placeholder to set up AnchorProvider
const MockWallet = {
  signTransaction: () => Promise.reject(),
  signAllTransactions: () => Promise.reject(),
  publicKey: Keypair.generate().publicKey,
}

// Create a connection to cluster
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("..."))

// Create an AnchorProvider using connection and mock wallet
const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, MockWallet, {})

// Set the provider as the default provider
setProvider(provider)

// Create a new Program
const programId = new PublicKey("...")
export const program = new Program(
  IDL as Idl,
  programId
) as unknown as Program<MyProgram>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeWallet with random keypair may be not the best option. If you look deeper into anchor typescript client, u will see, that Program client requires Provider interface and this interface has only one required field - connection, the rest is optional. So here is the best solution of ur problem:

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("..."))
const anonymousProgram = new Program<MyProgram>(IDL, PROGRAM_ID, { connection })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue by using `NodeWallet`

**Here is an example**

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import NodeWallet from "@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet";
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import ProgramIDL from "./thread_program.json";

async function main() {
  let connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
  let wallet = new NodeWallet(new Keypair());
  const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
    commitment: "processed",
  });

  const programId = ProgramIDL.metadata.address;
  const program = new anchor.Program(
    ProgramIDL as anchor.Idl,
    programId,
    provider
  );

  ...
}
```